# modifying Qt heightmap data visualization axys and correcting cut top bug

Tags: c++, qt, range, data-visualization, surface

1 ) I am super new with Qt and I am trying to plot my own map in the surface example , which I did, my map is rectangular and I need to keep it in the plot , my map is 400x2200 and when I show it in the example it makes squared and distorce a lot the plot. I am thinking if it is something related to

```
m_graph->setAxisX(new QValue3DAxis);
m_graph->setAxisY(new QValue3DAxis);
m_graph->setAxisZ(new QValue3DAxis);
```

2 ) the map is being cut on the top , it doesnt reach the real peak of my image and I normalized the map from 0 to 255, I noticed that the original map, mountain.png that comes with the example , goes from 55 to 197. I tried to set the Y range but it is not working.

[image: original image]

[image: aaplication[][1]]

The question is:
1) how to make a rectangular shaped graph , the squared graphic is corrupting my map.

2) how to change the z axis for not cutting the top of my map

Comment: You forgot to ask a question. Please see [ask].

Comment: Please read -> [mcve]

Comment: I edited and add the questions :The question is: 1) how to make a rectangular shaped graph , the squared graphic is corrupting my map.

2) how to change the z axis for not cutting the top of my map